# Draw simple box using curses

Tags: c, linux, unix, draw, curses

Just started to learn C and got a project using curses. I can't even get the simplest things to draw right now.

Want to do a box and have the following code and it doesn't work. The screens is just black.

What am I doing wrong?

```
#include    <curses.h>
int main()
{
    initscr();
    noecho();
    crmode();

    WINDOW * win = newwin(10, 10, 1, 1);
    wrefresh(win);
    refresh();

    getch();
    endwin();
}
```

Comment: could you elaborate on the problem. Is there a compiler issue? Or you are not getting the desired output?

Comment: BTW I don't know if I'm even using the right function. I need a box so maybe box() is better. I'm just struggling to under stand curses right now.

Comment: No output at all bust a black screen until I hit a key and the program ends.

Answer (score 11):

Try this.

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    initscr();

    WINDOW *win = newwin(10,10,1,1);

    box(win, '*', '*');
    touchwin(win);
    wrefresh(win);

    getchar();

    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```